# overriding PublisherImpl for filtering outpout messages

Tags: ros, python, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am preparing some multi-robot experiments and I would like to simulate some communication loss between robots.
I have one ROS node on each robot supervising the mission execution. These nodes publish some information about their own execution status to all other robots to maintain a correct execution.

The point is that I would like to filter the published messages to simulate that e.g., robot 1 can communicate with robot 2 but not with robot 3: the published message should then be sent to r2 but not to r3.

Looking at the Publisher implementation (python version), I think this is possible to implement by redefining the publish method at rospy.topics._PublisherImpl.publish and filtering correctly the set of 'connections' of the publisher to send only to the relevant subscribers.

That's where I need help: I don't see any easy way to say to the publisher that I would like to use my new ComSimulationPublisherImpl(_PublisherImpl) implementation instead of the original _PublisherImpl class... Is there an easy way to do so without having to reimplement all the rospy.topics package?

Thanks,

Charles

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209061/overriding-publisherimpl-for-filtering-outpout-messages/) by [CharlesOnera](https://answers.ros.org/users/22407/charlesonera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CharlesOnera](https://answers.ros.org/users/22407/charlesonera/) on 2015-05-12**:
I thought that implementing at the publisher level would scale better than having a specific relay node and could be done much more generic as the relay node would not have to know about all the nodes I have on my system. If you think you have a well-suited design, could you give more details please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe different design: not override the publisher but let all publish and subscribe on different topics and set up a muxer/republisher node in the middle that only republishes those topics you want; thereby selectively connects the nodes?

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0